# Let Monitor show the result returned by Module?

Tags: scoping, monitoring, localization

I wrote a simple `solver` to solve an equation with two parameters `a` and `b`. At the same time, I'd like to **observe** the result during the calculation with `Monitor`. However, the monitor cell only shows the parameter values of `a` and `b`, but the solution of the equation is not showed **during the calculation**. That is, it keeps showing `x`. The following example may demonstrate the issue.

```
Clear[solver]
newPts = {};
solver[a_, b_] := Module[{root, val}, root = x /. NSolve[x^5 - 2 x + a + b == 0, x];
val = Abs[root]; Table[If[val[[n]] < 1, AppendTo[newPts, {a, b} -> root[[n]]]; 
solver[a, b] = {a, b, root[[n]]}, Nothing], {n, 1, Length[root]}]]

pts = Monitor[Table[solver[a, b], {a, 1, 10, 0.1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}], {a, b, x}]
```

However, the solution is actually obtained by the solver, as can be seen by calling

```
solver[3,1]
(*{{3, 1, -0.286289 - 1.36775 I}, {3, 1, -0.286289 + 1.36775 I}}*)
```

I guess this is because `Table` (in the `Module`) effectively uses `Block` to localize values or variables, but I am unable to resolve this issue. Can anyone help with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "x" is symbolic, it never gets a value.

To monitor "root", you may introduce a dummy variable like e.g.:

```
Clear[solver]
newPts = {};
solver[a_, b_] := 
 Module[{root, val}, 
  dummy = root = x /. NSolve[x^5 - 2 x + a + b == 0, x];
  val = Abs[root]; 
  Table[If[val[[n]] < 1, AppendTo[newPts, {a, b} -> root[[n]]];
    solver[a, b] = {a, b, root[[n]]}, Nothing], {n, 1, Length[root]}]]

pts = Monitor[
  Table[solver[a, b], {a, 1, 10, 0.1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}], {a, b, dummy}]
```

Comment: ah, I still do not completely understand the syntax of `dummyVar=Var=...`. The `root` is a local variable of course. The `dummy` is a global variable since it takes the value of the last computation in the end.

Comment: "dummy = root = ...  " stores the content of the local root in the global variable dummy and makes it accessible globally.